# OK button not working in CKEditor plugin

Tags: plugins, ckeditor

I'm using:

https://github.com/frozeman/MediaEmbed

To embed youtube videos etc in CKEditor, and it works fine, except i've got an error in IE9... The more annoying thing is that it's not even showing up as an error, it's just not working!

In firefox the box opens up and then after adding the embed code, you click "ok" and it puts it in the editor, however in ie9, the box opens up, and you can paste your code the box, you can click the cancel button and the box closes, but if you click ok, nothing at all happens!

Any help appreciated, completely blown away by this now!

Code here:

```
       /*
    * Embed Media Dialog based on http://www.fluidbyte.net/embed-youtube-vimeo-etc-into-ckeditor
    *
    * Plugin name:      mediaembed
    * Menu button name: MediaEmbed
    *
    * Youtube Editor Icon
    * http://paulrobertlloyd.com/
    *
    * @author Fabian Vogelsteller [frozeman.de]
    * @version 0.1
    */
    ( function() {
        CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'mediaembed',
        {
            init: function( editor )
            {
               var me = this;
               CKEDITOR.dialog.add( 'MediaEmbedDialog', function ()
               {
                  return {
                     title : 'Embed Media',
                     minWidth : 550,
                     minHeight : 200,
                     contents :
                           [
                              {
                                 id : 'iframe',
                                 expand : true,
                                 elements :[{
                                    id : 'embedArea',
                                    type : 'textarea',
                                    label : 'Paste Embed Code Here',
                                    'autofocus':'autofocus',
                                    setup: function(element){
                                    },
                                    commit: function(element){
                                    }
                                  }]
                              }
                           ],
                      onOk : function() {
                        for (var i=0; i<window.frames.length; i++) {
                           if(window.frames[i].name == 'iframeMediaEmbed') {
                              var content = window.frames[i].document.getElementById('embed').value;
                           }
                        }
                        console.log(this.getContentElement( 'iframe', 'embedArea' ).getValue());
                        editor.insertHtml(this.getContentElement( 'iframe', 'embedArea' ).getValue());
                     }
                  };
               } );

                editor.addCommand( 'MediaEmbed', new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand( 'MediaEmbedDialog' ) );

                editor.ui.addButton( 'MediaEmbed',
                {
                    label: 'Embed Media',
                    command: 'MediaEmbed',
                    icon: this.path + 'images/icon.png'
                } );
            }
        } );
    } )();
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Which version of CKEditor are you using?

I tested it with [CKEditor 4.0](http://ckeditor.com/) and WFM in lastest Chrome, Firefox & IE9. It seems that your plugin has some issues in 3.6.x branch. Why don't you consider updating to the latest stable version?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, only just seen this. I am using CKEditor 4.